# Send a file for the user to save it

Tags: itext

Instead of quietly saving the pdf file generated through itext code to a specific location, i want it to show as a download to the user and than they may save it wherever they want. How can i accomplish this in itext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [CreatePdf](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=174) servlet from my book. Assuming that you're talking about a web application (your question doesn't give us that info), you are serving the document *inline*. If you want the browser to open a "Save As" dialog, you need to change the content disposition to *attachment*.

In Java, it's done like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

In C#, it's done like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
```

Comment: I have your book's digital version. Its a great book till now. Good job, man.